# Feed Validation SSL Error

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed, cloudflare

When I tried to validate my [feed](https://www.wphuman.com/feed/), [W3C Feed Validation](https://validator.w3.org/feed/) returns this error

`Server returned [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error`

My feed looks fine and shows a green padlock on chrome and firefox.
My feed is behind CloudFlare's universal ssl.
Feed Url: https://www.wphuman.com/feed/

How can I resolve the error?

Thanks!

*Update:* The feed works well on https://validator.w3.org/, but not https://validator.w3.org/feed/

Comment: works for me *This document was successfully checked as well-formed XML!*

Comment: I updated the W3C Feed Validation url which returns the error. Sorry for that

Comment: suffering the same problem, Feed doesn't pass validation with regards to Apple News publisher beta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably happening because the library being used by the feed validator service does not have support for the TLS ciphers being used by CloudFlare or due to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/861137) in OpenSSL.

The feed validator uses Python and the regular validator is Perl.  Most likely it is due to an issue with the feed validator SSL libraries that are available to Python on that system.

If you validate the feed by direct input it shows as valid and I tested your URL with a number of tools and all were able to access the site.